# ng-model name with variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a dynamic form that receives a array of jsons with the field to be displayed. My problem is in the `ng-model` and ng-required they are in the array,cant get the value to be in the `ng-model` name

This is my code:

the form containing the data

```
form_array : [
    {label: "Responsable", name: "dynamic", required: true},
    {label: "Username", name: "user1", required: true},
    {label: "Number", name: "user2", required: false},
    {label: "Age", name: "user3", required: false}
]
```

html to display the form fields

```
 <form name="form" class="form-submit">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div ng-repeat="fa in form_array ">
        <label>{{fa.label}} {{fa.name}} {{fa.required}}</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" 
            ng-model="requestForm.{{fa.name}}" ng-required={{fa.required}}></div>
    </div>
    <button id="resetbtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">Limpar</button>
    <button id="sendReport" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="requestForm.$invalid"
            ng-click="send(form)">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the

```
ng-model="requestForm.{{fa.name}}"
```

with following

```
ng-model="requestForm[fa.name]"
```

In JavaScript when you want to use a variable as a dictionary key, you use the `[]` accessor instead of dot.

Answer (score 0):

for `ng-model` try `ng-model=requestForm[fa.name]`

Comment: Doesnt get the variable name, ive tried that. And I need the to be `ng-model=requestForm.name`

Comment: @changez hm, maybe `requestForm[{{ fa.name }}]`

Comment: Please add some details to your answer so that both OP and future readers can benefit with the rationale behind the suggested solution

Comment: @user2954587 Sry it worked using `requestForm[fa.name]` instead of not appearing in the html when the info arrives into the controller it gets the fields